# Django exception_value error

Tags: django, json

I am trying to send data in a JSON format to my django app. When I try to use POST as below, I am getting error below. So, What is wrong with my posting way or views method.

**Edit:
The error message:**

```
<pre class="exception_value">&#39;Key \&#39;data\&#39; not found in &lt;QueryDict: {u\&#39;{ &quot;data&quot;:\\n        {\\n          &quot;name&quot;: &quot;Something&quot;,\\n          &quot;content&quot;: &quot;Anything&quot;\\n        }\\n}\\n\&#39;: [u\&#39;\&#39;]}&gt;&#39;</pre>
                    <table class="meta">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Request Method:</th>
                            <td>POST</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Request URL:</th>
                            <td>http://localhost:8000/api/recipes/item_new/</td>
```

Comment: Are you sure you pasted this right?  It looks like the whole function body is inside the `if POST:` suite.

Comment: Sorry for that, I have moved whole body one space to the left. However, I am getting an exception value error that I posted above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are posting raw JSON, not form-encoded data. You need to access `request.body`:

```
postdata = request.body
postdata = json.loads(postdata)
```

Note that this was called `request.raw_post_data` in versions before 1.4.

Comment: Thanks I changed, but for this time, I got that error @<h1>KeyError at /api/recipes/item_new/</h1>
                    <pre class="exception_value">&#39;name&#39;</pre>
                    <table class="meta">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Request Method:</th>
                            <td>POST</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Request URL:</th>
                            <td>http://localhost:8000/api/recipes/item_new/</td>

Comment: You now need `postdata['data']['name']`. You could have worked this out for yourself if you printed the contents of `postdata`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like wrong indenting to me. The line where you start processing `postdata` is in the same indented block as the part where you return the `HttpResponseBadRequest`. Move the whole block one space to the left and it should work.

Btw. better use 4 spaces for one indent. This is usual practice in Python development. In any case: one space is too hard to read and debug.

Comment: Sorry for that, I have moved whole body one space to the left. However, I am getting an exception value error that I posted above.